# deleting an array of pointer to struct

Tags: c++

i have the following struct:

```
struct Message {
    Agent *_agent;
    double _val;
};
```

and the following Ptrs array:

```
typedef Message* MessageP;
MessageP *_msgArr;
_msgArr = new MessageP[MAX_MESSAGES];
```

this is the method that inserts a Message to the array:

```
void Timing::AddMessage(Agent * const agentPtr, double val) {

    MessageP msgPtr = new Message;
    assert(msgPtr != 0);

    //assign values:
    (*msgPtr)._agent = agentPtr;
    (*msgPtr)._val = val;

    //add to messages array:
    assert(_msgArr != 0 && _waitingMsgs<MAX_MESSAGES);
    _msgArr[_waitingMsgs] = msgPtr;
    _waitingMsgs++;

}
```

My question is about the deletion of this array. I would like to delete the array and all allocated structs.
if i write:

```
delete [] _msgArr
```

will this delete also each allocated struct or will free only the allocated memory for the array?

Is the correct way is to go over the entire array with a for loop and write

```
delete _msgArr[i]
```

and at last wite delete [] _msgArr to delete the allocated array
?

thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using one of the standard library containers like a `std::vector` or `std::deque`?

Comment: I'm currently taking a course in c++, we haven't reached this material yet so its not allowed to use vector..

Comment: James has a point - the standard arrays are very useful (and often more resource efficient, if a little slower at times) - but as per the answer below, you still need to delete objects pointed to in the std containers.

Comment: Then the course is wrong. It should cover the STL and not pointers or C arrays.

Comment: @rob: So the course is teaching it backwards. It should first teach the simple, high-level stuff, and only later teach how this works under the hood. The way you're taught now you first learn to do it manually, and later learn to not to do it manually, but use library facilities instead.

Comment: @sbi: I actually prefer to learn anything in the method being used by rob's instructor. I feel it gives me a better understanding of the material, although it can certainly be more frustrating sometimes.

Comment: @sbi: I have never heard of a CS course being taught in any other way, and that has always been a source of deep concern for me. People should know how things work, yes, but they should know that there are other solutions. I have encountered a number of long-time "C++" programmers with little to no knowledge of the STL. Not to mention that many C++ teachers are really C teachers in thin disguise, I think this is a serious problem in the industry.

Comment: @mpminnich: So you would learn Java by looking at how the VM implementation does things under the hood? Developers are used from other languages to accept that things "just work". I have taught half a dozen C++ courses in that way (use `std::string`, `std::vector` etc. from day one, teach smart pointers the same lesson `new` is taught) to students who knew Java and to students who knew none or next to none about programming and it worked well.

Comment: @Jon: A heartfelt `+1` from me, although I have heard of at least one other course: mine. `:)` If you're interested in teaching C++, have a look at _Accelerated C++_. To me this was a revelation.

Comment: @ Ragster: That was just beaten to death in another question. Using standard containers is NOT slower than doing it manually. So std::Vector is just as fast as using an array.

Comment: @sbi:  I wish you had taught the C++ class at my (soon to be former) place of work... I think I'd have seen a lot less bad code if people knew how to use the STL correctly and if they didn't consistently confuse templates with macros.  :(

Comment: @James: Is your location a good indicator for your soon-to-be-former employer? `:)` Anyway, I have given seminars in the industry (teaching students was for a good part done because I actually liked it), but from what I know of you here, you are at least as qualified as I am to do teaching in the industry.

Comment: @sbi:  Actually, no, ha ha; I was a bit eager to change my location and am not actually moving there until next week.  For better or for worse, I'll be learning to love C#.  We'll see how that goes. :-)  (I've given a few lectures on various topics, namely RAII and smart pointers, but they never allowed me to teach a class; I do think that would be fun, though).

Comment: @James: Ha, you fooled me. Good luck with that! Re C#: Just look at the tags of the questions I asked (many `C#` tags) and at those of the answers I give. C# is as cute as a puppy. And I so do miss C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete []` will call the destructors on the struct pointers, which doesn't dispose of the structs or the `_agent` members, which itself points to memory.   You could call `delete _msgArr[i]._agent` and then `delete _msgArr[i]` in a loop, which will dispose of the `Agent` and then the `Message`.

First, though, you need to know who should get rid of the `Agent`s, and when.  If these are owned by another data structure, you shouldn't get rid of them when getting rid of `_msgArr`, and looping over `_delete _msgArr[i]` followed by `delete [] _msgarr;` is all you need.

If you do need to delete the `Agent`s also, you have three reasonable choices.

First, you can give `Message` a destructor that will delete its `_agent`.  It should also have a copy constructor and assignment operator defined then, either to pass ownership or to copy, or else define them as `private` so any attempt to use them will be a compile-time error.

Second, you could change the `Agent *` to a smart pointer, so that the extra memory will be deleted when the `Message` goes away.

Third, you could go through the loop I suggested above when getting rid of the array.

Unless you have good reasons to keep the code C-compatible, I'd suggest that you use a `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Message> >`, and have `Message` contain a `boost::shared_ptr<Agent>` rather than an `Agent *` (if you don't have to dispose of the `Agent`s, `Agent *` is fine).  At that point, you don't need to worry:  when `_msgArr` goes out of scope, all the memory is cleaned up properly.

Comment: Can u explain your second option - the use of a smart pointer that will delete all memory when Message is deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to loop over all elements and `delete` them manually before calling `delete[]` on the array.

Comment: So from what i understand, delete [] _msgArr doesn't call delete on each cell. what is the meaning of delete _msgArr without the []?

Comment: i mean, does it also deletes the allocated array?

Comment: @rob:  If `_msgArr` points to an array created by `new T[N]` (the array form of `new`), then `delete _msgArr` yields undefined behavior.  You _must_ delete it using the array form of `delete`.

Comment: It calls the destructor on each cell, but since the cells are pointers and not objects there is no destructor action.  Look into using a smart pointer type for array elements if you want auto deletion of the allocated structs.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately yes. But you can simplify the thing with a couple of lines if you are going to do this a lot.

```
#include <algorithm>
// might already exists in a boost header (i don't remember)
template <T>
void delete_func(T* e) {
    delete e;
}

// then, to delete your array :
std::for_each(_msgArr,_msgArr+MAX_MESSAGES, delete_func);
delete[] _msgArr;
```

but i suggest not to do so. You could use a std::vector with auto_ptr or shared_ptr (depending on your use case). So you won't have to delete each element yourself because the auto_ptr will do so. You will just have to delete the std::vector

Answer (score 0):

Except for the fact that it is within a class member function and uses `new` and `delete`, this is C code. You don't need to check the result of `new` (allocation errors will throw), you shouldn't do your own dynamic arrays (that's what `std::vector` is for), and you shouldn't manage dynamically allocated using dumb pointers.

What you want is `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Message> >` or one of boost's pointer containers.